# Double slit experiment with polarised light

Tags: waves, visible-light, conventions, interference, double-slit-experiment

If I had a double slit, and one slit is covered with vertical polariser, and the other with horizontal polariser, and a +45° polariser placed after the double slit (in between the screen and the double slit). Now what pattern would I get if I shine a +45° polarised light on the double slit (let it be case 1), and also what pattern it would be if I shine -45° polarised light all after shining +45°polarised light(let it be case 2)? If the answer is, in both the cases I see the interference pattern but phase shifted with 180° in the second case, then whats the meaning of putting a +45° polariser after the double slit, it would be the same even with or without that polariser after the double slit right.

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question under the title, "Why are my interference patterns completely out of phase?" on January 19th 2019?

Comment: No, i did not. I know why interference pattern are completely out of phase, but i don't know what the results will be if i perform an experiment like this.

Comment: My fault. Careless reading of your original question.

Comment: No, not a problem thank you.

Comment: Please try answering it, if you know how the results of the experiment would be.

Comment: "if you shine -45° polarised light you will still get an interference but phase shifted of 180°. " ..... do you have a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) "in both the cases I see the interference pattern but phase shifted with 180° in the second case" That is correct.
[image]

(b) "then what's the meaning of putting a +45° polariser after the double slit; it would be the same even with or without that polariser after the double slit – right?" No. Without the 45° polariser after the double slits you wouldn't get ANY interference pattern. That's because two oscillations at right angles to each other can't give an interference pattern. For example, they can never cancel with each other. But passing them through the ±45° filters produces oscillations with the same alignment, and therefore capable of interfering.

[I think that most people find this surprising at first. One reason for puzzlement is that the horizontal and vert polarised light from both slits must surely *contain* the +45° components that we know *do* give us an interference pattern. Yes, but they also contain the –45° components that give the opposite sort of interference at any point!]

Comment: But, what I read is when you shine a +45° polarised light on double slit with two orthogonal polarisers with respective to each other(one vertical other horizontal), on two slits, gives you an interference pattern, on the same double slit setup, if you shine -45° polarised light you will still get an interference but phase shifted of 180°. But what you said is on the flip side of what i read.

Comment: To get the interference patterns you need a 45° polariser after the double slits. Please see (b) in my answer.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-happens-in-a-double-slit-experiment-if-you-put-relatively-perpendicular-polarization-filters-on-the-slits/answer/Mark-John-Fernee?ch=10&oid=285018523&share=d32f5042&srid=u2y5oN&target_type=answer     i request to see this once.

Comment: I think you need double headed arrows. Linear polarization is not a vector a direction , it's a tensor alignment.

Comment: @JEB  I've taken on board your excellent advice (back in 2019) on 'alignment' versus 'direction', but I really do want single-headed arrows here for field *directions* in my diagrams. As I've said, they represent the fields *at a point in time*. Note that I'm referring to the polaroid pass-orientations as 'alignments'.

Comment: @Merugu Arun Kumar Did you mean that you'd like *me* to read this? The website needs me to sign up and I'm trying to psych myself up to do this ...

Comment: @PhilipWood. Your polarizations are correct ... but your comment on "interference" is not.  Think about single photons, if we just fired them one at a time .... every photon has its own path ... they never interfere in terms of cancelation. (that would be violation of conservation of energy)

Comment: @PhysicsDave I'm not quite with you... You're surely not denying that we can demonstrate the destructive interference of light? Can you say exactly which sentences in my answer you object to? I'm not claiming (in case you thought I was) that destructive interference occurs at all points, but only at certain points in an interference pattern.

Comment: We are all taught in high school and in classical optics courses about the "interference" of light .... I think we are still using textbooks whose optics chapters haven't been edited since the 1940s!  But experiments like Taylors in 1909 and  "Demonstration of single‐electron buildup of an interference ... " by Tomomura (1989) in Japan have shown we get the same pattern whether we fire 1000s of particles per second or a particle every 1000 seconds (or days etc).

Comment: That's right. Where lies the disagreement?

Comment: "That's because two oscillations at .... "  we don't need 2 photons for "interference"  .... each photon "interferes with itself"!  IMO you're providing classical principles.  IMO the "interference" is present in both +/- 45 cases. (my answer above).

Comment: Yes, I've provided a classical explanation. Polarisation and two-source interference are very well modelled classically. I'm certainly not claiming that we need 2 *photons*!

Comment: Just at least 2 photons ..... If 1000 scientists each did a DSE experiment in their own lab and just fired and recorded only 1 photon ..... then if they got together for a big conference and combined results .... voila the pattern would emerge!

Answer (score 1):

Using Philip's polarizations above .... it is easy to see that 50% of photons get thru each step (polarizer) .... so net 25% get to the screen.

If photons are getting to the screen they will always "interfere" but interfere does not mean cancelling (that's a violation of energy conservation).  Each photon determines its own path and in the DSE dark areas have no photons ... the paths to these parts of the screen are low probability (Feynman path integral).  The bright areas have all the photons.